# Quicktime Playback using Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, video-streaming, quicktime, embedding

I have been reading the [JavaScript Scripting Guide for Quicktime](https://web.archive.org/web/20111010140734/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/bQTScripting_JavaScri_Document/QuickTimeandJavaScri.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001526-CH001-SW5) and in there it gives you an example on how to play a video using a javascript command.  Unfortunately whenever I try, I am given the error `document.Camera_0.Play() is not a function` in firebug.

My code is as follows:

```
        QT_WriteOBJECT_XHTML(
            'video_placeholder.jpg',
            '200', // 4:3
            '150',
            '',
            'enablejavascript', 'true',
            'obj#id', 'Camera_0',
            'emb#name', 'Camera_0',
            'href', 'http://userwww.sfsu.edu/~infoarts/technical/howto/sound/test.mov',
            'controller', 'false',
            'target', 'myself'
        );
```

and

```
    $(".camera_live_clickable").click(function() {
        document.Camera_0.Play();
    });
```

`document.Camera_0` is a valid object according to FireBug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by adding a placeholder movie and changing the `href` and `target` params to a `qtsrc` param with `autoplay` off:

```
        var qtEmbed = QT_GenerateOBJECTText_XHTML(
            'video_placeholder.mov', //'video_placeholder.jpg',
            '200', // 4:3
            '150',
            '',
            'enablejavascript', 'true',
            'obj#id', 'Camera_0',
            'emb#name', 'Camera_0',
            'controller', 'false',
            'qtsrc', 'rtsp://quicktime.tc.columbia.edu:554/users/lrf10/movies/sixties.mov',
            'autoplay', 'false'
        )
```